# Consumer grade vs professional audio

Tags: audio, tracks

Newbie issue!

I was given 12 miniDV tapes and the Canon ZR900 camera they were recorded on to transfer onto memory sticks.  I used FW400 into a Dell XPS 9100 to capture using Filmora. No problems at all. Excellent AVI's

At the same time I was also given 12 other miniDV tapes that were recorded but using a 'professional' camera of an unknown brand.  When capturing those tapes using the consumer camera I have no audio.  Actually I can hear waaay in the distance the audio with occasional 'bursts' of sound when I crank up the volume.  What Might be the first obvious issue I may be having.  Thank you.

Comment: The first thing I would do is find another machine to play them on to isolate the problem. The tapes might be recorded as DVCam rather than DV, although the tapes are the same, the data is recorded differently. Are you seeing pictures?

Comment: Can you post pictures of the physical cassettes? That would help answer @stib's question about the format difference.

Comment: Problem is that you can record DVCam on DV tapes. The tape just runs at a higher speed, so a 60minute DV tape gives you 46 minutes of DVCam

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  The video is excellent on playback using the Canon camcorder, I'm only lacking the audio, or to be precise, the audio is barely audible unless cranked.   I think I'll locate another consumer camcorder as first suggested.  I've hit the books on understanding the many video formats now and hopeful I'm not playing back a DVCam format unless the Canon consumer camera can playback that format. The tapes are TDK miniDV ME.  Thanks for the suggestions. You have no idea how much it helps.  Off to find another camcorder. I love a challenge!

Comment: I've been looking on eBay and see a bunch of decks that will do miniDV and or DVCam.  JVC dsr11,  JVC BR dv3000u,   JVC BR Dv600 etc.  Anything I should look out for or suggestions on getting one of these models. Maybe a Sony, don't know the difference.  Thanks.